# kcfinder not showing tab in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, integration

I installed CKEditor and KCfinder the way it's described on their pages. Now CKEditor is showing up nicely and works well, but KCfinder isn't showing up in the CKEditor images tab. I did everything according their manuals/installation guides and searched on the internet for other ways to implement KCfinder. I could'nt find a single guide that really worked or one that describes my problem.

Is there anyone who faced the same problem and solved it or possesses the right knowledge to help me out of this frustrating situation?

I really appreciate every single input. I'm quite new to web developing and Stackoverflow is such an amazing platform and knowledge database for me as a newbie!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the "Upload" tab and the "Browse Server" button missing from CKEditor's Image dialog, I would ensure that the paths are correct for your integration.

http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/docs/integrate